# Difference between Dynamic Web Module 3.0 and 2.5 in Java EE?

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

Can anyone tell what are new features added in Web Module 3.0 and from where I could get release notes of same?

Answer (score 10):

One of the differences is we don't require web.xml and we could annotate our serlvets getting called.

Comment: @BalusC This is still a very useful fact, though I do agree that this should have been a comment.